# more in detail vs in more detail

Tags: meaning

I wondered if there is any difference between 'more in detail' and 'in more detail'.

- Could you explain that more in detail?
- Could you explain that in more detail?

Comment: They are used interchangeably, but I would say "more in detail" should be understood with a comma like: "more, in detail" meaning please explain further, and do so in detail. Whereas "explain that in more detail" I would take as "explain that again, but with more detail. You may can see how they mean the same thing and a native AmE speaker such as myself would not think enough to differentiate between them before saying one or the other. I will also add that 'in more detail' is used much more commonly in my experience and I would also most likely use that version. It seems to flow better.

Comment: [In the UK.] I've never heard the first. The second is more idiomatic.